# How should I pass a variable to my HTML file from app.js?

Tags: html, node.js

I am currently finishing the Authentication side of my server and could use some help.
I'm trying to disable and enable specific tabs depending on wether an User is authenticated. As I was following a [video (part 8)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFVqL5aIjSE&index=8&list=PLpPnRKq7eNW3Qm2OfoJ3Hyvf-36TulLDp), the author was using if conditions ( {{#if}} {{/if}} ) in the HTML file to check if a variable in the app.js file was true or not.
I tried it but with no success. Is there a  I need to pass in the top of the HTML file? Or is there a better way of doing it?

app.js:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.isAuthenticated = req.isAuthenticated(); //variable in question
    next();
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        {{#if isAuthenticated}} //check if this variable is true or not and if so, show the following elements
        <li class="nav-item" class="navbar-right">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/Profile">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" class="navbar-right">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/Logout">Logout</a>
        </li>
        {{else}}
        <li class="nav-item" class="navbar-right">
          <a class="nav-link" href="Register.html">Register</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" class="navbar-right">
          <a class="nav-link" href="Login.html">Login</a>
        </li>
        {{/if}}
      </ul>
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit 1: Better explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is to use view engine (e.g. EJS) and then render the view with given variables.

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
```

^ to set view engine (firstly `npm install ejs`)

```
app.set('views', './views')
```

^ allows you to set your views directory

Then create views directory and, for example, index.ejs file:

```
<h1> <%= title %> </h1>
```

Next, write your route:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Sample title' }) // refers to views/index.ejs
})
```

Within render method you can pass an object (2nd argument) with parameters that you can use in your view. Further info: http://www.embeddedjs.com/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I don't think I explained myself well enough. Apologies for that. Basically, I need to show/hide certain HTML based on wether a variable in the app.js is true or false. Just not sure on how to do that

Comment: @JoaoBM best practice is set a template engine. engine compiles the view before rendering so by passing a model object and have a simple if clause you can show hide whatever you want: res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!' }) https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html and also in case you don't know how to write an if clause in pug https://pugjs.org/language/conditionals.html

Comment: Oh I see. Then I was the one who misunderstood. Apologies @sofalse . I will give  a look into it and update this with news. Thank you both!